# In 걱정하지, why does the first ㅈ sound like ㅊ?

Tags: pronunciation

I read that some consonants such as ㅈ are aspirated at the beginning of a sentence or phrase or something. However, I can't really find the explanation for this particular scenario where they sound aspirated.

For the first one ㅈ, I see a ㄱ before it, but I can't find the pronunciation rule for it.

I found this on [Korean Phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology): When the second and third consonants are homorganic obstruents, they merge, becoming fortis or aspirate, and, depending on the word and a preceding |l|, might not elide: |lk-k| is [lk͈].

However, I don't really understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard pronunciation, which, unfortunately, is in Korean, covers it.

> ## [*Korean language standard, Part Ⅱ (“Standard pronunciation”), §6 (“Tensation”)*](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000102), Clause 23.
>
> [image: The NIKL logo]
>
> ---
>
> A “ᄀᅠ,” “ᄃᅠ,” “ᄇᅠ,” “ᄉᅠ,” or “ᄌᅠ” following a “ㄱ”-sounding final (“ᅟᅠᆨ”, “ᆩ”, “ᆿ”, “ᆪ”, or “ᆰ”), a “ㄷ”-sounding final (“ᆮ”, “ᆺ”, “ᆻ”, “ᆽ”, “ᆾ”, or “ᇀ”), or a “ㅂ”-sounding final (“ᆸ”, “ᇁ”, “ᆲ”, “ᆵ”, or “ᆹ”) gets tensed (unaspirated).
>
> 받침 ‘ᅟᅠᆨ(ᆩ, ᆿ, ᆪ, ᆰ), ᆮ(ᆺ, ᆻ, ᆽ, ᆾ, ᇀ), ᆸ(ᇁ, ᆲ, ᆵ, ᆹ)’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ᄀᅠ, ᄃᅠ, ᄇᅠ, ᄉᅠ, ᄌᅠ’은 된소리로 발음한다.
>
> - 국밥 [국빱]
> - 깎다 [깍따]
> - 넋받이 [넉빠지]
> - 삯돈 [삭똔]
> - 닭장 [닥짱]
> - 칡범 [칙뻠]
> - 뻗대다 [뻗때다]
> - 옷고름 [옫꼬름]
> - 있던 [읻떤]
> - 꽂고 [꼳꼬]
> - 꽃다발 [꼳따발]
> - 낯설다 [낟썰다]
> - 밭갈이 [받까리]
> - 솥전 [솓쩐]
> - 곱돌 [곱똘]
> - 덮개 [덥깨]
> - 옆집 [엽찝]
> - 넓죽하다 [넙쭈카다]
> - 읊조리다 [읍쪼리다]
> - 값지다 [갑찌다]

---

The *standard* pronunciation follows the way Koreans find easier to pronounce. Though I can't quite explain *why* it is easier and how I learned those vast, overwhelming tons of rules. There must be some academic papers about it.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, almost rule on pronunciation is to find "easy pronunciation
way"

When we pronounce 걱정 [걱정], 김밥 [김밥] (gimbap; making a rice
roll in dried laver), it is stressful.

Hence we have 걱정[걱쩡], 김밥[김빱]. Here ㅉ may sound ㅊ.

Other similar examples are : 곡식 [곡씩] crops, 숙식[숙씩] board and
lodging.